# h2o glm grid search in Python: Rollups not possible, because Vec was deleted error

Tags: python, h2o

This seems to be related to the issue specified [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3761) and seems resolved now but I am doing a grid search (alpha values for GLM - gamma with log family) using Python API and getting the following error (for all alpha values):

Rollups not possible, because Vec was deleted: $04ff12000000fffffffff6664ae26e403db2c741167b02d01a0f$

`

```
Hyper-parameter: alpha, [0.0]
failure_details: 1701
failure_stack_traces: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1701
    at hex.optimization.OptimizationUtils$MoreThuente.evaluate(OptimizationUtils.java:362)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.fitIRLSM(GLM.java:691)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.fitModel(GLM.java:945)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.computeSubmodel(GLM.java:1029)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.computeImpl(GLM.java:1098)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:173)
    at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.compute2(GLM.java:543)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1255)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

`

Changing to L-BFGS solver I get:
`

```
Hyper-parameter: alpha, [0.0]
failure_details: Rollups not possible, because Vec was deleted: $04ff12000000ffffffff29c907ce45483f9f244f54c4d0$%;K
failure_stack_traces: java.lang.RuntimeException: Rollups not possible, because Vec was deleted: $04ff12000000ffffffff29c907ce45483f9f244f54c4d0$%;K
    at water.fvec.RollupStats.get(RollupStats.java:322)
    at water.fvec.RollupStats.get(RollupStats.java:352)
    at water.fvec.Vec.rollupStats(Vec.java:847)
    at water.fvec.Vec.checksum_impl(Vec.java:866)
    at water.Keyed.checksum(Keyed.java:69)
    at water.fvec.Frame.checksum_impl(Frame.java:558)
    at water.Keyed.checksum(Keyed.java:69)
    at hex.Model$Parameters.checksum_impl(Model.java:394)
    at hex.Model$Parameters.checksum(Model.java:325)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch$2.filter(GridSearch.java:298)
    at water.KeySnapshot.filter(KeySnapshot.java:65)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch.buildModel(GridSearch.java:290)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch.gridSearch(GridSearch.java:213)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch.access$000(GridSearch.java:68)
    at hex.grid.GridSearch$1.compute2(GridSearch.java:135)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1255)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

`

Comment: Does single h2o.glm run successful?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/CQmaJVm5_jQ

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, what worked for me was having `enable_assertions = False` in `h2o.init()`.

```
h2o.init(..., enable_assertions = False)
```